# OSGi and Maven detect use of private package

Tags: maven, osgi

I'm starting a project writing OSGi bundle and using Maven as the build management tool. My understanding is for an OSGi bundle you can choose which package you would like to keep private/public.

Here is the question:

- If I am depending on a bundle that declares `com.example` package as exported package and declares `com.example.internal` as private package, is there any way, during build time, to detect use of `com.example.internal` (build should fail)?

It would be awesome if that can be detected during development time by Eclipse, but I highly doubt it can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use Eclipse's Plugin Development Environment (PDE), an OSGi-aware set of tools. It won't let you compile against internal packages, so it gives you the development-time checking. Unlike maven's bundle plugin, it's manifest-first rather than code first, which isn't to everyone's taste.

To integrate PDE with Maven, the best bet is to use the Maven [Tycho plugin](http://www.sonatype.org/tycho). This gives you a fully OSGi-aware compilation stage in Maven.

Comment: thanks I will try the Tycho plugin, and make this accepted answer once it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In think you will find a lot of support for this in bnd(tools). In general, I find these culprits by watching the Import-Package statement, which is nicely visualized in bndtools. There is some support in bnd(tools) to generate warnings/errors when an import package has no import range, which happen when you import a private or non-existent package.

Comment: Unfortunately bndtools is alternative to Maven and they can't be used together.

@Peter, if all `bnd` instructions would be written in expternal `bnd.bnd` file, can you point to help showing how `bnd` command line tool can extract some value of that?

Comment: If you're starting a new project I suggest take a look Bndtools. In the upcoming release we support full support for the maven repositories: local, remote (Nexus/Artifactory), snapshot, and release. you can automatically install a JAR into the local m2 repository after every (incremental) build cycle, making it easy to work with other maven projects. Though I am obviously biased, the Eclipse support in Bndtools is lightyears ahead of m2e.